# How to add an organizer to Online meeting created using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, office365api

I have an admin account to create Online meetings of Graph API. Suppose I want to create online meetings for others to be the organizer, how should I do it? I do not see any parameter for that while creating the meeting.

Comment: You can set the organizer while creating meeting using Graph API as told by Carl Zhao

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onlineMeetings");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);         
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer "+token);
request.AddHeader("accept-language", "en");
request.AddHeader("accept", "application/json");            
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"startDateTime\": \"2020-09- 
         28T19:30:34.2444915-07:00\",\n\"endDateTime\": \"2020-09- 
         28T20:00:34.2464912-07:00\",\"subject\": \"User Token Meeting\"}", 
         ParameterType.RequestBody);
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

To retrieve the token:

```cs
var client = new RestClient("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant- 
                 Id}/oauth2/v2.0/token");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);         
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");         
request.AddHeader("grant_type", "password");
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
     "grant_type=password&client_id={client-Id}&client_secret={client- 
      secret}&scope={scopeurl}&userName={username}&password={password}", 
      ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var json = response`.`Content;
var JSONObject = JObject.Parse(json);
var token = (string)JSONObject["access_token"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can request `/me/onlineMeetings/createOrGet`API, and then add the organizer to the request body.

[image]

please see: [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-createorget?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)